# 2D object recognition using MATLAB

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, matlab, image-processing

Have you any idea about implementing 2D object recognition with MATLAB? 
Which characteristics of objects can feed a neural network? 
It's [my training data-set](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/datasets/downloads/Obj_DB.tar.gz) (provided by ETH University of Switzerland)  
 
What is the start point?

There are 5 view of each object, and whole objects are 66.

[image]

Comment: please be more specific, at the current moment the question is too vague. Also it is better to give a preview of data in the question. I for one am very wary of downloading unknown archive files from the internet.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: I suppose you have the data imported in Matlab, so can you post the preview of data as an output from Matlab prompt.

Comment: it would also help a lot if you provided the context of your problem. 2D object recognition is very vague. One or two sentences of what are you actually trying to achieve would clarify things a lot. Sorry for nagging.

Comment: I've specified number of objects and pictures of each object in 5 different pose (some of them http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7148/capturewa.png). I want to train a neural network with this set of pictures and after finishing the learning phase of neural network use that neural network to detect those specified objects in a new given picture.

Comment: question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817684/object-recognition-using-matlab

Comment: I asked this question there.

Comment: I like [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4409066); it lists most of important keywords, has some nice ideas itself and contains state-of-art from 2007.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817684/object-recognition-using-matlab/6821670#6821670 didn't address your question ?!

Comment: it helped. But i some codes may help more

Answer (score 1):

People tend to use DHOG (Dense Histograms of Orientations of Gradient), which is closely related to SIFT and other image description method for this purpose. There is another commonly used image description method called SURF.

You can take a look at [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org).